# AJAX call results in status 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url:"myurl",
    async:true,
    success:function (data) {
         //....
    },
    complete:function (x, st) {
         //....
    },
    error:function (x, st, e) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(x));
    }
});
```

This is the ajax call.
If I try to access the "myurl" in browser, it works fine.
But the Ajax call always results in error.
If I stringify the xhr, it looks like this:

```
{
  "readyState": 0,
  "responseText": "",
  "status": 0,
  "statusText": "error"
}
```

Comment: Did you check the console/network tab what caused the error? Seeing that [the readyState is 0, the request may have not left your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#Properties).

Comment: Side note, `async:true` is the default so no need to specify that.

Comment: Request URL:http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780201485677&store=ebook

Request Headers
GET http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780201485677&store=ebook HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Referer: http://book.douban.com/subject/1419359/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17

Query String Parameters
keyword=9780201485677&store=ebook

Thanks for the tip, just checked, in the network tab of chrome, I see the above. Still not sure what it's the problem.


@JosephtheDreamer

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer by the way, I am working on a chrome extension, in which case cross origin ajax is allowed.

Comment: in chrome extension you need to set `"permissions": [ "http://www.google.com/" ]` in the extension definition file, have you done that ( http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html )

Comment: @JonathanLonowski there is a redirect involved, but the weird thing is that if I call this url: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780735619678&store=ebook it works fine, but if i call this url: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780201485677&store=ebook, then it results in error. they both have redirect.

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes, i have done that. and it works, sometimes ...

if I call this url: barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780735619678&store=ebook it works fine, but if i call this url: barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780201485677&store=ebook, then it results in error.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski the error thrown is just an empty string. and i dont this jquery is denying it, because if I call this url: barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780735619678&store=ebook it works fine, but if i call this url: barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780201485677&store=ebook, then it results in error. i'll try setting crossdomain to true.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski just tried setting crossdomain to true, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely where those URLs are redirecting -- only 1 stays in-domain:

```
http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780735619678&store=ebook #->
http://www.barnesandnoble.com/...

http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?keyword=9780201485677&store=ebook #->
http://search.barnesandnoble.com/...
```

You'll need to include `search.barnesandnoble.com` in your permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://www.barnesandnoble.com/",
    "http://search.barnesandnoble.com/"
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i did not notice that they redirecting to different domains.